# Unresolved id with Kotlin Android Extensions on Gradle 3.3.0 and Android Studio 3.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

After I updated my Android Studio and gradle to the version 3.3.0 I can't compile my App. The views provided by the Kotlin Android Extensions doesn't work. I am having compilations errors with 'Unresolved reference: xxx' for my all views referenced.

On previously version from gradle and Android Studio my code works.
I have tried to clean and rebuild my project, invalidate caches and restart the Android Studio and create a new project and copy and paste my code to it, but all this doesn't work.

My project .gradle contains:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.20"
    ext.play_sevices_version="16.0.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.fabric.io/public"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4"
    }
}
```

My app .gradle contains:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
       ....
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 28
       ...
       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), 
    "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.StephenVinouze:KinApp:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$play_sevices_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$play_sevices_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$play_sevices_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.taskail:simple-places-search-dialog:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.duanhong169:colorpicker:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04"
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
}
```

**Edited:**
When I updated my projects dependencies, Android Studio and migrate it to use the 'androidx' some of my ids declared in layout files was deleted (I don't know why, but I think it could happened when of my actions also tried do clean the project removing unnecessary ids declaration), ids used in constraint layout wasn't deleted.

Comment: Did you update `Kotlin plugin` in Android Studio settings?

Comment: Yes, I have updated everything with the last stable version in Android Studio.

Comment: Are the IDs referenced, still present in you xml layout file?

Comment: Some IDs are gone out of the xml layout files, as I edited my question. The reason I don't know exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try as follows

- File | Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Deleting .idea folder
- Running gradlew clean
- Re-import the project

If still problem remains then just removed apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' , synchronize gradle plugin and then I added it again.

Comment: Just adding to the list of suggestions, deleting the .cache folder may be also helpful on cases like this.